How to Find the Midpoint of a Plan to Draw a Perspective?
"If one wants to draw the perspective of a plan, one must find the center of that plan on the picture plane," says perspective information. After finding the center of the plan, a perpendicular line must be drawn from this center point. The book says that lines should be drawn 15 degrees to the right and 15 degrees to the left of this perpendicular line. This is because the line drawn determines the angle of view. You can see an example of this in the bottom left of the photo on the left.
So what do I need to do to find the middle of a plan? If the plan is a rectangle and it is at different angles, how do I find the center of the plan? Because in some perspective drawings it looks like the "angle of view" is not in the center of the plan.

Edit: In answer to @Scott's answer:
Yes, but why wasn't the picture I shared made with the method you describe? The visual angle is too far off center. This situation is even present in some architecture books.

This sounds like a math/geometry question, so i'm voting to close.

Simply the center is where the viewer (point of perception, camera, eye...) is in relation to the object being projected. You can arbitrarily choose the location and direction of the "camera".

(assuming you may mean "plane" not "plan")
Draw a path from one corner to its opposing corner. Repeat for each set of corners. The intersection of those paths will be the center.

Since I could not share a picture, I shared my question above as a "comment".  Why are some "visual point" not in the center of the plane?

The point of perception (the camera) is arbitrary..... someone could be standing left of center and looking.. or right of center and looking.

I see. So, after arbitrarily determining the point of perception (the camera), we should also determine the center of the plan, so that the line coming from the center of the plan need not be perpendicular: T mean we will have a "point of view (the camera)" with two equal angles going from the camera to the plan. As far as I understand, this is what needs to be taken care of.
